# Installing Programs

Tags: installation

I'm new with using Linux, so I don't know, how to install downloaded programms (downloaded with Firefox). Could anybody please give me a discription. Best would be in german, but english is ok too.

Comment: This is the nice place to start [Installing Software](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallingSoftware)

Comment: Unlike Windows in Ubuntu it is **not recommended** to install downloaded software in case you are not an experienced user. See links in my answer where you will find explanations why in German.

Comment: Oops, didn't mean to mark it as that question

Comment: See: http://askubuntu.com/questions/405600/how-does-software-work-in-ubuntu/405719#405719

Answer (score 1):

You'll find everything you are looking for in the free Ubuntu manual [Erste Schritte mit Ubuntu](https://ubuntu-manual.org/downloads). It's a pdf ebook with lots of screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

I speak Dutch but not German so I will just answer in English: for a walk trough you can have a look [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-desktop-latest) I think it is a good walktrough. you can burn the image to a blank dvd, but I prefer to use a usb because it is re-usable and your settings will be saved for the next time you boot into it. I would advise to click the 'try Ubuntu' option to check if your hardware works under Ubuntu (in most cases it will but it is better to find out before you install) good luck and have fun in Ubuntu!

Answer (score 0):

An awesome place to find help in German, and to have up to date guides to almost all procedures you need to know when running Ubuntu is the [Wiki maintained by the German user forum](http://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Startseite). The following articles address application installation basics:

- [Grundlagen](http://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Grundlagen)
- [Anwendungen hinzufügen](http://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Anwendungen_hinzuf%C3%BCgen)
- [Paketverwaltung](http://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Paketverwaltung)

There also is an [active forum](http://ubuntuusers.de/) there where you a welcome to ask question in German.